# Can't reliably verify texture for SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I am trying to write a test that verifies a SKSpriteNode in my scene has the correct texture.
The test looks like this:

```
let sceneSprite = scene.childNodeWithName("sceneSprite") as SKSpriteNode!

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: expectedSpriteTexture)
sprite.size = sceneSprite.size // 102.4 x 136.533

XCTAssertTrue(sceneSprite.texture!.sameAs(sprite.texture!), "Scene sprite has wrong texture")
```

The **sameAs** method for SKTexture is implemented with the following extensions:

```
extension SKTexture {
    func sameAs(texture: SKTexture) -> Bool {
        return self.image.sameAs(texture.image)
    }

    var image: UIImage {
        let view = SKView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size().width, size().height))
        let scene = SKScene(size: size())
        let sprite  = SKSpriteNode(texture: self)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(view.frame))
        scene.addChild(sprite)
        view.presentScene(scene)
        return self.imageWithView(view)
    }

    func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func sameAs(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        let firstData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
        let secondData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        return firstData.isEqual(secondData)
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes the tests passes and sometimes the test fails. I have change the code so it save the images on failure, and discovered the test fails because even though the first image is correct, the second image is completely **black**.
What can be done so the test will pass reliably?
This failure is happening on the simulator for iPad2.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change, and it seems to make the test pass reliably

```
func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

What ideas do people have for why this allows the test to succeed?

Comment: Seem like I was wrong. The reason that the test is passing with the change above both images are now completely white.